# Barman not able to connect: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I'm trying to setup streaming replication to a Barman server.

Barman config is pretty much basic, I'm using `backup_method = postgres`.

```
[barman]
barman_home = /var/lib/barman
barman_user = barman
log_file = /var/log/barman/barman.log
log_level = DEBUG
archiver = true
backup_method = postgres
backup_options = concurrent_backup
compression = gzip
minimum_redundancy = 1
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 DAYS
retention_policy_mode = auto
streaming_archiver = true
wal_retention_policy = main
configuration_files_directory = /etc/barman.conf.d
```

I'll call the DB server `pg`

```
[pg]
description = "pg"
ssh_command = ssh postgres@pg.example.com
conninfo = user=barman dbname=postgres host=pg.example.com port=5432
```

I've configure hba rules and setup a `.pgpass` file in `barman`'s home `/var/lib/barman/.pgpass`.

A test connection to `pg` server works just fine:

```
barman@b01:~$ psql -c 'SELECT version()' -U barman -h pg.example.com postgres
                                                             version                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.7 (Debian 10.7-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

However `barman check pg` fails miserably and I have no idea why:

```
$ barman check pg
Server pg:
        WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
        PostgreSQL: OK
        is_superuser: OK
        PostgreSQL streaming: FAILED (fe_sendauth: no password supplied)
        wal_level: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 1)
        pg_basebackup: OK
        pg_basebackup compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: None, pg_basebackup version: 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
        pg_basebackup supports tablespaces mapping: OK
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: FAILED (please set it accordingly to documentation)
        pg_receivexlog: OK
        pg_receivexlog compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: None, pg_receivexlog version: 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
        receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)
        archiver errors: OK
```

Is there a better way how to debug authentication issues? Is the `.pgpass` even loaded under `barman check`?

```
pg.example.com:5432:postgres:barman:s3cr3tP2ssw0rd
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking [barman's source code](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman/blob/937d9ce8a4ff4b851134391238cf0ae6a6ba6f44/barman/postgres.py#L286), I've realized that barman is actually overwriting the `conninfo` string:

```
    # Override 'dbname' parameter. This operation is required to mimic
    # the behaviour of pg_receivexlog and pg_basebackup
    self.conn_parameters['dbname'] = 'replication'
```

Which isn't very intuitive, thus the `dbname` in `.pgpass` should include `replication` db:

```
pg.example.com:5432:replication:barman:s3cr3tP2ssw0rd
```

Comment: Barman doesn't have a choice.  If you want to do physical replication, you need to connect to the "replication" pseudo-database.